# Error in stdio.h file?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header, stdio

I'm trying to write and run "Hello World" in C.

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    #include <stdio.h>
    puts("Hello world.");

    return 0;
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error in the Terminal:

```
In file included from ex.c:3:
/usr/include/stdio.h:353:54: error: function definition is not allowed here
__header_always_inline int __sputc(int _c, FILE *_p) {
                                                     ^
1 error generated.
```

It appears to me it's picking up a syntax error in the stdio header file? I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: The error is in the code you wrote. The standard library headers are meant to be included at **file scope**.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>` move to before `main`. error of definition nested function.

Comment: _"It appears to me it's picking up a syntax error in the stdio header file"_... now, that's something... :D

Answer (score 1):

You want to do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    puts("Hello world.");
    return 0;
}
```

Your `#include` directives should pretty much always come first in your file.  When you write `#include <some_file>`, you're telling the preprocessor to basically copy all the text from some_file into your program.  For example, `<stdio.h>` includes the `puts` function declaration.  By including `<stdio.h>` as the first thing in the file, you're able to tell the compiler about `puts` so that it can use it later on.

*Edit: thanks @Olaf for pointing out that #include is a directive and not a statement*

Comment: Note: `#include` is not a statement, but a preprocessor directive. You must not have statements at file-level.

Answer (score 0):

Section 7.1.2 **Standard headers** of the C standard says, in part:

> If
>   used, a header shall be included outside of any external declaration or definition, and it
>   shall first be included before the first reference to any of the functions or objects it
>   declares, or to any of the types or macros it defines.

That means you are not allowed to include any of the standard headers inside the body of a function.

Your code is violating that rule — it isn't required to work.  Don't do it!